# Select count for total times foreign key exists in table with join

Tags: mysql, count

My table setup is as follows

### Shortlist

| id (primary key) | property_id(foreign key) | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2 |
| 2 | 101 | 2 |
| 3 | 103 | 4 |
| 4 | 100 | 1 |
| 5 | 100 | 3 |
| 6 | 101 | 1 |

### Property

| id (primary key) | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |
| 103 | 4 |

I then have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `s`.`user_id`, `s`.`property_id`, `p`.`id`, `p`.`account_number`, COUNT(`s`.`property_id`) as `shortlistCount` 
FROM `shortlist` `s` 
INNER JOIN `property` `p` ON s.`property_id` = p.`id` 
WHERE s.`user_id` = "2" 
GROUP BY s.`property_id` 
LIMIT 10
```

I want to add a count field alias as `shortlistCount` that returns the total number of times each `property_id` field appears in the `shortlist` table. (or `id` field in the `property` table, whichever is easier in this context)

For example, the `property_id` of `100` appears `3` times in the shortlist table.

So the result should be

```
| user_id | property_id | id  | account_number | shortlistCount |
|---------|-------------|-----|----------------|----------------|
| 2       | 100         | 100 | 1              | 3              |
| 2       | 101         | 101 | 2              | 2              |
```

However, `shortlistCount` currently always returns `1`

How can I can update my `shortlistCount` alias to return the above result?

Comment: You're counting the property_Id that you're filtering based on User_Id = 2, for which there is ony one of each though. Aside - you so not need *distinct* - `group by` already means you have distinct rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the `property_id`s you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.user_id, s.property_id, p.id, p.account_number, 
 (select Count(*) from Shortlist s2 where s2.property_id = s.property_id) shortlistCount 
FROM shortlist s 
JOIN property p ON s.property_id = p.id 
WHERE s.user_id = 2
LIMIT 10;
```